# Extending knockout.js mapping with moment.js support

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, momentjs

Are there any possibilities of extending the knockout mapping plugin to handle the mapping of different types when unmapping?

I have this model:

```
var Model = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.requestFrom = ko.observable(moment().subtract("days", 1));
    self.requestTo = ko.observable(moment());
    // additional properties.
};
```

And to get a plain JavaScript object out of that, I'm doing:

```
var model = new Model();
var obj = mapping.toJS(model, {
    "ignore": ["requestFrom", "requestTo"]
});
obj.requestFrom = model().requestFrom().toISOString();
obj.requestTo = model().requestTo().toISOString();
```

I would like to avoid handling the translation of moment objects manually, and instead write some extension to knockout mapping that knows how to handle objects of type moment, and return them as their ISO string representation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know that this isn't what you are asking for, but you can use Knockout binding handlers with moment.js to manipulate dates and times

Comment: In this case it's because I need to convert it to a plain JS object before using it in an AJAX request.

Comment: If you use a binding handler then the underlying format of your date/time observable won't change - the only thing that changes is what the user sees. So whenever it's time to post back to the server, you can do a `ko.toJS(model)` or `ko.toJSON(model)` and send that data back. Your server will be receiving the dates/times in the same format in which you retrieved them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `toJSON()` is called automatically on your object when you pass it as an Ajax parameter.

It may not be directly the answer that you're looking for, but adding a custom `toJSON()` on your Models works pretty good I think. You have very precise control on what part of the data is send and in what format.

```
var Model = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.requestFrom = ko.observable(moment().subtract("days", 1));
    self.requestTo = ko.observable(moment());

    // additional properties.

    self.toJSON = function()
    {
        return { 
            requestFrom: self.requestFrom(), 
            requestTo: self.RequestTo(),
            otherProperty: self.otherProperty()
        }
    }
};
```

You can than use it directly on your Ajax requests, without converting it manually.

```
var model = new Model();

$.ajax({
    url: '/test/PersonSubmit',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: model
});
```

Note that the default toJSON() implementation of moment() is already toISOString(). See the source code of moment.js:

```
// add aliased format methods
moment.fn.toJSON = moment.fn.toISOString;
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I think this is a better solution. Regarding your comment about moments implementation of toJSON, wouldn't that mean that if I did ko.toJS(model), it should give me an object where requestFrom/To are ISO strings? Doing that, I'm getting an error: "TypeError: this.clone is not a function. moment:1711 return this.clone().lang('en').format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ");" Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't ring a bell to me! If you have a fiddle I can take a look. 
If you would take this approach I wonder if you really need ko.toJS though, because you can pass your model directly to the $.ajax or $.post and it automatically calls toJSON for you on each object.

Comment: The problem is I'm using Knockout, so passing the object without calling toJS, would just serialize the knockout observables. I will look into creating a Fiddle sample, hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: as you can see in the example, I unwrap the observables in the ViewModels manually within the `toJSON()` method. This way you always have full control what you send, and don't need `toJS`: every viewModel is reponsible to return his own data unwrapped in the `toJSON` method.

Note that the `toJSON` for sub ViewModels is also called, so this works with complex hierarchies.

Comment: Ah, I see Dirk. And I'm actually using that approach now. I just got the understanding that I could use the toJS method from knockout without implementing my own toJSON method. But it makes sense, and I'll stick with that approach, because as you say, I have full control over how the data is unwrapped. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

have you thought about using prototype to extend the `ko` object?  I would clone the `observable` method into a new `momentObservable` method that could then be called like so:

```
var Model = function () {
  var self = this;

  self.requestFrom = ko.momentObservable.subtract("days", 1));
  //other operations
```

};

Comment: Thanks for you answer Brian. I do however prefer Dirks solution :-)

Comment: of course! It is rather elegant and has a performance advantage!  Figured I'd offer this alternative in the event your app has heavy `moment` usage, (or in case a future SO user has similar question with that particular distinction.) Happy Hacking! Thanks for the vote!